# Convert string with numbers and lowercase characters to string with numbers, lowercase and uppercase characters

Tags: php, hash, radix

I've a functions that generates unique ids. The output format contains only numbers and lowercase characters. The problem is, these id's are quite long, thus not very user-friendly.
My question is, is there a possibility to convert this id in an id which also contains uppercase characters, making the string much shorter, because the values each character can be is 62 (10 + 2*26) instead of 32 (10 + 26)? I'm writing this function in PHP

Answer (score 0):

this function can get you random string with your Length

```
 function Random($length){//40-95--97-126
 $id='';
 for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){  
   while(1) {  
     $id1=rand(48,122);
     if(($id1!=91)and($id1!=92)and($id1!=93)and($id1!=94)and($id1!=95)and($id1!=96)and($id1!=58)and($id1!=59)and($id1!=60)and($id1!=61)and($id1!=62)and($id1!=63)and($id1!=64)and($id1<123)and($id1>47)){
       break;
     }
   }
   $id.=chr($id1);
 }
 return($id);
}
```

for test

```
echo Random(10);
```